# Schrodingers equation for an electron in a periodic potential derivation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform, crystals

In Kittels *Introduction to Solid State physics*, when deriving schrodingers equation for an electron in a periodic potential, we begin by writing the wave function as a Fourier series $\psi = \sum_k C(k)e^{ikx}$. where $k=2\pi n/L$ due to the born von karman boundary conditions. Similarly, we write the periodic potential as a Fourier series $U(x)=\sum_GU_Ge^{iGx}$ where $G$ is a reciprocal lattice vector.

We then substitute these into the Schrodinger equation and get
$$\sum_k \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}k^2C(k)e^{ikx}+\sum_G\sum_k U_GC(k)e^{i(k+G)x}=\epsilon\sum_k C(k)e^{ikx}\tag{1}$$
I understand everything up till this point. The author then states that "each Fourier component must have the same coefficient on both sides of the equation and hence we get the *central equation:*"
$$(\frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m}-\epsilon)C(k)+\sum_GU_GC(k-G)=0 \tag{2}$$
This I do not understand. I don't understand why the fourier components should all be the same and I also do not understand how we can end up with equation 2 from equation 1. Any help on deriving equation (2) from equation (1) would be most appreciated as I can't seem to connect these two at all

Comment: Is that supposed to be a lowercase $k$ in eq (2)?

Comment: Yes I'll correct it now. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can first re-write eq. (1) a bit to see it clearer.

$$ \sum_k \frac{\hbar}{2m}k^2 C(k)e^{ikx} + \sum_k\sum_GU_G C(k-G) e^{ikx} = \epsilon\sum_kC(k)e^{ikx}$$

We have only made the substitution $k' := k+G$ and then renamed $k'$ back to $k$. Now we can pull out the factor of $e^{ikx}$ on both sides and get
$$\sum_k e^{ikx} \left(\frac{\hbar}{2m}k^2 C(k) + \sum_GU_G C(k-G) \right)= \sum_k e^{ikx} \left(C(k)\epsilon\right)$$

In order for this equation to hold *for all $x$*, the terms in the perentheses must individually be equal for each $k$. Otherwise, even if the sums match for some $x$, move over a bit to $x+\Delta x$ and they will in general not match anymore. Therefore, the terms in the parentheses must be equal for each $k$, giving your Eq. (2).

Comment: Thanks for the great response. Okay its pretty much all clear for me now. Just one question about the substitution. We begin with $ \sum_k\sum_GU_G C(k) e^{i(k+G)x}$. If we now substitute $k'=k+G$ we get $ \sum_{k'-G}\sum_GU_G C(k'-G) e^{ik'x}$. The first sum has the index $k'-G$ which runs over all $k'=n2\pi/L$. How do we interpret the $G$ in the index though? Does it simply remain constant as $k'$ runs over all possible $k'=n2\pi/L$. Or do we note that all vectors of the form $k\pm G$ are ultimately of the form $n2\pi/L$ and simply discard the G in the index?

Comment: Ah that's a good point. Since we sum over *all* $k$ it doesn't matter where the sum over $k$ starts. So for each $G$, the sum over $k$ has a different "starting point", but we sum over all of them anyway. It's a bit like counting squares on a chess board; if you count all of them, it doesn't matter if you start counting in the middle, any of the corners, or anywhere in between (it's not a perfect analogy, but I hope it gets the point across).

Comment: Okay perfect, thanks so much for the help!